Why is Angular not applying mat-checkbox-disabled CSS to disabled mat-checkbox
I have a really strange unexplained issue between my localhost and production builds of an Angular 10.2.3 based application website.
On the production server, when we disable a mat-checkbox, we can see in the underlying html that Angular is correctly applying a mat-checkbox-disabled css class to the checkbox control as well as removing the ng-valid css class. We use the mat-checkbox-disabled  css class to apply an opacity setting to style the control to indicate its disabled.
Here is what that looks like. In this form, checkboxTwo has logic so that when checkboxOne is checked it then sets itself (checkboxTwo) to disabled:

Now the unexplained. On our localhost copy of this application, exact same angular version, here is the same form when the checkboxTwo has been disabled by checkboxOne being checked:

You can see from the html source that the ng-valid class has correctly been removed, however, the mat-checkbox-disabled class does not get added!
I can't explain this so I'm asking here for help on what could be the cause.

Please share your html and ts.

If you are applying css within component please try this one,
:host ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-disabled {     pointer-events: none; }

Already doing that but the issue is not with the CSS in my component per se. The issue is that Angular never adds the class to the component at runtime! So the .mat-checkbox-disabled class never gets set for the CSS to affect.
